# Running against Edge on selenium-standable server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, webdriver-io

I am trying to run Edge in selenim-standalone server on my Mac.

I’ve followed the CLI command to install but when I try to with wdio project I get the following error:

```
ERROR webdriver: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService
```

Started my server using this command:

```
selenium-standalone start --drivers.chrome.version=98.0.4758.80 --drivers.chrome.baseURL=https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
```

I have not had much luck finding another person having the same issue.

- Server is running with node 14
- Wdio project is running with node 16

any thoughts on what it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

I ended up running the install command in node v16 and that worked.  I did have to delete selenium-server jar file the first time because it was corrupt.  Though I re-ran the install command again it worked.